# Blazor Server Entity Framework Core: data column encryption not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, encryption, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to make my user data more secure by encrypting sensitive data like `Firstname` and `Lastname` of a client. But when I use the following code from medium and update my database, the data doesn't get encrypted after adding an new client.

Source:
https://medium.com/emrekizildas/encrypt-your-database-columns-with-entityframework-1f129b19bdf8

Other suggestions for encrypting data are also welcome!

These are the things I tried:

- Updating from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 5.0 and changing package version
- Creating 128bit key instead of "test123456"
- AesEncryption: https://github.com/Eastrall/EntityFrameworkCore.DataEncryption

Model/DbContext:

```
using EntityFrameworkCore.EncryptColumn;
using EntityFrameworkCore.EncryptColumn.Extension;
using EntityFrameworkCore.EncryptColumn.Interfaces;
using EntityFrameworkCore.EncryptColumn.Util;
using Globals.Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;

private readonly IEncryptionProvider _provider;

public Model()
{
    Initialize.EncryptionKey = "test123456";
    this._provider = new GenerateEncryptionProvider();
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.UseEncryption(this._provider);
}
```

Example entity:

```
using EntityFrameworkCore.EncryptColumn.Attribute;

namespace Globals.Entities
{
    public class Client
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [EncryptColumn]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [EncryptColumn]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public Client(string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            FirstName = firstName;
            LastName = lastName;
        }
    }
}
```

Commands for reinstalling the database:

```
drop-database
remove-migration
add-migration initialCreate
update-database
```

Comment: I recommend hashing the sensitive date instead of encrypting. because, hashing is a one-way function.

Comment: Did you inject `IEncryptionProvider ` in startup.cs or program.cs?

Comment: @AlirezaK Thank you for the advice. I also did not inject the provider in startup.cs (or program.cs). But do you have an example of this because the sources I used, don't include it.

Comment: I think this link can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/74744534/4444757

Comment: @AlirezaK I tried your solution in startup.cs but it seems that the encryption method is broken I think. Do you have example how to use hashing (in entity framework core)? Thank you for the help until now.

Comment: You're welcome. You can refer to the follow repo to understand how hashing works in Blazor. https://github.com/Kamalifar/BlazorServerCookieAuthentication-master/blob/main/Services/SecurityService.cs